# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" despite of using invokeLater

Tags: jtable, refresh, event-dispatch-thread, mouselistener, invokelater

I'm trying to update a JTable (here: prosumerTable) programmatically, using SwingUtilities.invokeLater to start it out of the EventDispatchThread-

to be exact i have to replace the content completely, hence i'm just removing all rows and adding new ones  - this works fine:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            controlledProsumers = v.getControlledProsumers();
            if (model.getRowCount() > 0) {
                for (int i = model.getRowCount() - 1; i > -1; i--) {
                    model.removeRow(i);
                }
            }

            Iterator<Prosumer> it = controlledProsumers.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Prosumer p = it.next();
                model.addRow(new Object[] { p.getProsumerName(), p.getProsumerType(), p.getChangeRate(), p.getMinimalOutput(), p.getMaximalOutput(),
                        p.getRealOutput(), p.getPredictedOutput(), p.getCredibility(), p.getReliability(), p.getPrice(), new MiniOutputPanel(p), p });

            }
            prosumerTable.packAll();
        }
```

But if i add a MouseListener

**MouseListener:**

```
prosumerTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

            if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                JTable target = (JTable) e.getSource();
                int row = target.getSelectedRow();
                // int column = target.getSelectedColumn();

                Prosumer p = (Prosumer) model.getValueAt(row, model.getColumnCount() - 1);
                CommandInspectNode c1 = new CommandInspectNode(p, false);
                c1.execute();
            }

        }
    });
```

to react on click Events i get an Exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(Unknown Source)
at gui.prosumerViews.subpanels.controlledProsumersAvPP.ControlledProsumersAVPPPanel$1.mouseClicked(ControlledProsumersAVPPPanel.java:85)
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

namely here, where i try to access the tableModel:

```
Prosumer p = (Prosumer) model.getValueAt(row, model.getColumnCount() - 1);
```

I assumed using the EventDispatchThread to update SwingComponents would be sufficient method to avoid exceptions of this type - or am i barking up the wrong tree here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `addMouseListener`,

```
int row = target.getSelectedRow();
```

Above statement will **return -1** if there is no row selected.

So you are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

So before calling the `model.getValueAt(row, model.getColumnCount() - 1);` statement try to check whether there is/are rows selected or not.

```
int row = target.getSelectedRow();
// int column = target.getSelectedColumn();
if(row != -1) {
   Prosumer p = (Prosumer) model.getValueAt(row, model.getColumnCount() - 1);
   CommandInspectNode c1 = new CommandInspectNode(p, false);
   c1.execute();
}
```

Comment: thank you! -so this problem is not about threads, but rather about clicking into a JTable during the short moment it is empty (because all the rows have been removed) -thus i did not select any row and got -1 as return value - is this correct ?

Comment: Yep. Before performing an `mouseAction` check whether there are rows or not in the table and if there are there then see whether a row is selected or not.